# How to configure vysper api to communicate from one xmpp server to another xmpp server

Tags: xmpp, apache-vysper

I am trying to implement a project where any client from one `xmpp server` can communicate to a client who belongs to another xmpp server. Both the servers are written using `vysper api`.
How can I write server program or module so that my objective will fulfill?